# Google Play Games Service in Unity doesn't authenticate

Tags: unity-game-engine, authentication, google-oauth, google-play-games

GPG service does not work

It shows the native GPG window, but when it’s closed the `PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate()` callback returns `NetworkError`

In the Google Play Console:
Created "Game service”.

- In the “Game details” section, added a description 512x512 and 1024x500 icons.
- In the “Linked apps” section, added an android application and completed authentication (OAuth 2.0 key was automatically created)
- In the “Achievements” section, created an achievement with a description and a 512x512 icon.
- In the "Testing" section added a gmail account for testing
- In the “Publishing” section, clicked Publish.

In the Google API:

- Activated Google Drive API and Google Play Android developer API (without creating any keys)
- Checked the SHA-1 in the OAuth key for Android and in “Release management”> ”App singing”> ”App signing certificate”

In Unity:

- Downloaded the latest release from https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity
- In Window> Google Play games> Setup> Android setup, copied the xml format text from the “Achievements” section of the Google Play Console using the “Get resources” link, the ClientID format is 123456789123456-fffffffffffffffffffffffff.apps.googleusercontent.com

The test build was signed with the same key as the application posted on Google Play with the same Company name and Product Name

```
PlayGamesClientConfiguration config = new PlayGamesClientConfiguration.Builder()
.RequestIdToken()
.Build();

PlayGamesPlatform.DebugLogEnabled = true;
PlayGamesPlatform.InitializeInstance(config);
PlayGamesPlatform.Activate();

PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(SignInInteractivity.CanPromptAlways, ((SignInStatus status) =>
{
        if (status == SignInStatus.Success)
        {
            print( $"Welcome {PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.GetUserDisplayName()}\n");
        }
        else
        {
            print($"Fail:{status}");
        }
}));
```

On debugging in Unty Console I have

```
<i>AndroidPlayer(ADB@127.0.0.1:34999)</i> Returning an error code.
 #0 0x443df5a (libunity.so) GetStacktrace(int) 0x25
 #1 0x4e788b6 (libunity.so) DebugStringToFile(DebugStringToFileData const&) 0x169
 #2 0x49875fe (libunity.so) DebugLogHandler::Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, core::basic_string<char, core::StringStorageDefault<char> >, Object*) 0x65
 #3 0x498754e (libunity.so) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, ScriptingBackendNativeStringPtrOpaque*, ScriptingBackendNativeObjectPtrOpaque*) 0xb5
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across this post while trying to find the answer myself and now that I know the answer I thought I would add it in here.... so that I can no doubt discover it the next time I forget how to do this. The issue is caused by the minification as @CherryCoke stated.

The solution can be found here: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/README.md#decreasing-apk-size

You have two options: either turn off the minification or tell the minify process what to ignore when doing the minification.

If you want to minify your build (which makes sense to me for a release) then you can do so by selecting "Custom Proguard File" in the Publishing Settings area of the Android build in the Player Settings.

[image]

Once you have added this in you will need to update the proguard-user.txt file that is specified. The path is displayed under "Custom proguard File".

For google play services then the entries you need to add can be found at: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/blob/master/scripts/proguard.txt

Answer (score 0):

I just saw this. I had the same error. What I did to fix it was I toned down the bytecode stripping in the project settings. When I checked the unity developer console, I noticed the error stating that my game couldn't find the library for GooglePlayGames.

While this is not the IDEAL answer, it's a temporary fix. The Ideal answer is creating a Link.xml file that tells the compiler not to strip out library .so file.
(Which, I am searching for at the moment, and how I came across your question.)